# Add folder to my .app on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I have a java application and want to create a .app for it using the jar bundler on a Mac, but my problem is that I have some of my resources in a folder and the jar bundler only allows me to add files or resources and not folders. So if anyone has any solutions please share it here. Otherwise i would have to keep all my resources in a single folder and change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution to my problem with the help of this link http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/
Bundled the jar files using the jar bundler,i had to change the destination of my other resource files to the current folder holding my .app file